# Vaadin flow grid prevent itemClickListener() to fire on click on buttons in ComponentColumns

Tags: vaadin-flow

With vaadin 23.1.x you can set a itemClickHandler when a user click on a item/row in the grid with `myGrid.addItemClickListener(..)`

This works fine.

But if you have a component column, with a button in it, then the ClickEvent of the Button is fired and also the `itemClickListener` of the grid row.

Is there a way to prevent the button click from also triggering the itemClickListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this method to add the listener them you can

```
myGrid.getElement().addEventListener("item-click", 
    event -> ...)
.addEventData("event.stopPropagation()");
```

I'm not 100% sure if the even is item-click or just click.

Comment: Depending on what components are in the component column, this hack is not necessary. But thanks for it